# Google Map Api, Gray BOX, Map not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my project I am plotting the waypoints in the map through Google Map API it was working fine a few days ago but now it's only displaying the markers and route but not showing the map instead of that it's showing gray background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true">
</script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if(module=='Vehicles'){

        var x = '<div id="mapdiv" style="width:100%;height:600px;margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>';
        
        
        
        var v1 = jQuery("#Vehicles_editView_fieldName_cf_1309").val();
        var v2 = jQuery("#Vehicles_editView_fieldName_vehicle_name").val();
        var v3 = jQuery("#Vehicles_editView_fieldName_vehicle_number").val();
        

        if(v1!="" && v1.includes(", "))
        {
            jQuery("body").append(x);

            var v = v1.split(", ");
            var l1=v[0];
            var l2=v[1];
            var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(l1, l2);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();   
            
            
            function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
                marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            } 
            function bindInfoWindow2(marker, map, infowindow) {
                marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
                    infowindow.close(map, this);
                });
            }

            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv"), {
                zoom: 18,
                center: myLatLng1,
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng1,
                map,
                icon: siteurl + 'uploaded_files/vehicle_marker.png'
            });

            //extend the bounds to include each marker's position
            bounds.extend(marker.position);


            var x = '<h4 style="text-align:left;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold">Vehicle Name: <span style="font-weight:300">'+v2+'</span></h4><h4 style="text-align:left;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold">Vehicle No.: <span style="font-weight:300">'+v3+'</span></h4>';
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, x);

            bindInfoWindow2(marker, map, infowindow);
        }

    }
    })

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It was working recently but now it's not showing the map only showing markers and route tried to debug but didn't catch the actual issue.

[Map showing only marker but the map background is gray no tiles are showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSgzd.png)

**In inspect element one of errors is coming**

**https://maps.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.maps.mapsjs.v1.MapsJsInternalService/GetViewportInfo**

**400 bad requests.**

**Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.__vtrftk=sid:a45953c^**

**but I am not sending any of the tokens I provide only the waypoints in the function.**

It was working perfectly from all locations in the server, but now only when I ran a test file in my server root it's working perfectly

Comment: As the error said: the JSON is invalid. Remove the trailing comma from map!

Comment: can you please kindly elaborate on this, as I am not getting which trailing comma you are referring to?

Comment: Comma, not command. `center: myLatLng1,` <-- that comma does not belong here.

Comment: I have removed the comma but still, the issue didn't get resolved.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fXFNGd3

Comment: What is the exact error now? Please update question. Bad request still means, that you call it with data the API does not accept.

Comment: The exact error is that the map background only shows blank grey colour only the markers are visible and when I zoom in or out its does the functionality but the background still shows blank and in console i get the same error "https://maps.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.internal.maps.mapsjs.v1.MapsJsInternalService/GetViewportInfo" - Bad request but when i create a file in my root directory and run the same thing then it doesn't shows any errors and map is also visible there.

Comment: Please give the exact error message (from the request) not what it looks like. Dump the data what is sent.

Comment: Now it's solved I had not given the specific version that's why the error was coming, I appreciate your help regarding this.

Comment: There's a public bug that's somehow similar to this, you might want to check it out if it is so: https://issuetracker.google.com/296891213

Answer (score 5, accepted):

choose for a specific Google Maps API script (version 3.53) with your API key.
Something like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&?v=3.53&key=YOURAPIKEY&sensor=true">
```

This ensures that your webpage will always use the specified version.

Comment: In my case i was using angular google maps connector and version is given as "weekly", when i changed to a specific version like 3.53 , it worked like charm and solved the problem.

Comment: const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "your map api key",
  version: '3.53',
  libraries: ['places'],
})